# scipy starts slow for the first time

Tags: python, scipy

I am using scipy intensively for various purposes. I have noticed that the first time the python code is compiled, it starts very slow. later on, it is very fast.Is there any work around for this trouble?

Comment: Can you give more details on the individual steps that you are doing, and which specifically appear slow in what circumstances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the libraries that scipy links to are quite large, especially the linear algebra libraries. On slow disks or network file systems, simply loading these libraries into memory takes a long time. However, once they are read, they go into the filesystem cache so subsequent loads are pretty fast. You will have to do further testing on your particular setup to determine if this is the case or not.